# Factorial inequality

Tags: inequality, factorial

How to show that $$10^{124}<100!<10^{180}$$
I believe I'm not supposed to use a calculator. I thought of factorizing the powers of $10$ or using the Stirling's approximation, but I still end up with hard mental math in both.

Would Stirling's approximation actually be sufficiently rigorous to show that this inequality holds true? It's an approximation after all.

Comment: try counting how many factors of 2 and 5 are in 100!

Comment: @OpenBall close, but not quite there.

Comment: @AliCaglayan that's what I already tried when I meant "factorizing the powers of $10$"

Comment: You could also try Stirling's approximation with bounds.

Comment: Oh, mental math?  Add that in for the question, I'd like to see how that goes.

Comment: @OpenBall what if $10^{180}<100!<10^{200}$?  The thought process is good, but not quite there yet.

Comment: @SimpleArt I read $100^{124}$ instead of $10^{124}$, so I thought there was something wrong with the question.

Comment: $\ln (n!) = (n+1/2)\ln n - n + \ln \sqrt{2\pi} + O(n^{-1})$, divide by $\ln 10$ and Stirling's yer uncle.

Comment: Btw. would Stirling's approximation actually be sufficiently rigorous to show that this inequality holds true? It's an approximation after all.

Comment: @Daphne Yes, Stirling's approximation can be made into the form of good inequalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the $\log:$ (all base 10 here)

$$\log(100!)=\log(1)+\log(2)+\log(3)+\dots+\log(100)\\<\underbrace{\log(10)+\log(10)+\dots}_{10}+\log(20)+\dots\log(100)$$

where we take $10$ of each, intervals of $10$.

$$=10(\log(10)+\log(20)+\dots+\log(100))=10(10\log(10)+\log(10!))<166$$

Thus, we have

$$100!<10^{166}$$

On the other side, we could notice that

$$\log(1)+\log(2)+\log(3)+\dots+\log(100)>\underbrace{\log(1)+\log(1)+\dots}_{10}+\log(10)+\dots+\log(90)$$

Same manner as last time but in the less than side.

$$\log(1)+\log(1)+\dots+\log(10)+\dots+\log(90)=10(9\log(10)+\log(9!))>145$$

Thus, we end up with

> $$10^{145}<100!<10^{166}$$

Interestingly, a much better bound than required.

Comment: Does arriving at $145$ or $166$ require knowing the log tables (or having a calculator)?

Comment: @BrianTung I think we don't even have to arrive at exactly $145$ or $166$ in the first place since the bounds are sufficiently large enough for simpler aproximations.

Comment: @BrianTung  are these good enough bounds for the problem?$$4<5\log(5)<\log(10!)<4\log(5)+5\log(10)<3+5=8$$ since $5^4$ and $5^5$ are easy enough to calculate by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$$
100! > 1^{9} \times 10^{22} \times 32^{69}
$$

which will take care of the first inequality after some massaging, and also that

$$
100! < 10^{9} \times 31^{22} \times 100^{69}
$$

which will take care of the second inequality after similar massaging.

---

ETA: Simple Art's answer gives better bounds, but this might actually be close to what was intended by the problem poser.  (That is, the resultant bounds are pretty close to what is asked for.)

Comment: Care to explain more?  Oh, my bad.  Did not read the bases well.

Comment: @SimpleArt: The first nine terms are greater than (or equal to) $1$, but less than $10$, the next $22$ terms are greater than (or equal to) $10$, but less than $32$, and the last $69$ terms are greater than (or equal to) $32$ and less than (or equal to) $100$.  Did I mess something up?  Wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: Lol, I think you are fine.  Indeed, the results are very close to the problem posed.